# Finding Members with 2 Roles in Discord [Using Discordjs]

Tags: discord.js

I am making a discord bot using discord.js, and what I want to do is to have the bot find members with Roles A *and* B, and list them in an embedded message. Currently, I have:

```
else if (message.content === (!'guns') && message.channel.id == '732740415056380044') {

        let team = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'WindStar Team');
        let awper = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'AWPer');
        let rifler = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'Rifler');

        const Members1 = awper = awper.filter(val => !team.includes(val)).map(member => member.displayName);
        const Members2 = rifler = rifler.filter(val => !team.includes(val)).map(member => member.displayName);

        const embedmesage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Preferred Guns')
            .setColor(0x00AE86)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'AWPers', value: `${Members1.join('\n')}` },
                { name: 'Riflers', value: `${Members2.join('\n')}` },
            );
    message.channel.send(embedmesage);
    return console.log('Preferred gun roles command for windstar team executed');
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to cross-check members who have the WindStar Team role and AWPer role, and send the list of all members who have those roles into an embed. I am also trying to cross-check members with the WindStar Team role and the Rifler role, and send the list of those members into an embed.

Answer (score 0):

```
let awper = message.guild.roles.find('name', 'AWPer');

awper.members //Either .toArray() or .map(m => m.displayName)
```

I think, I dont have my bot in front of me to test

Comment: this only finds members with the AWPer role. Trying to find members with both the WindStar and AWPer role.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is maybe too late at this point but I'll give my solution anyway. (using discord.js v12.5.1)

`<Message>` = your message instance

```
let roleMembers = <Message>.guild.roles.cache.filter(role => role.name === "AwPer" && role.name === "WindStar").members

// displaying the role members
roleMembers.map(member => member.user.username)
```

Basically you are getting all the roles in a guild a cache and filtering them to display the roles you want.

This should work ^. Unless you are using a breaking version of discord.js